# Adding custom information after displaying comments in Wordpress, only in certain post type

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show some calculated information after each comment, which are planned to be displayed only in 'product' post type. I have no problem with making the function work, it is showing what I want, but it also causes fatal errors on my website, for example the Comments section in admin panel. How can I make sure that these information are only shown in post type of 'product' and doesn't cause any errors anywhere else? My attempt is as follows:

```
function comment_significance_indicator ($content, $comment) {

    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;
    global $post;
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

    if ($post_type === 'product') {

    //some stuff happens here
    return $content . $blabla;

    else {
        return $content;
    }
}

add_filter("comment_text","comment_significance_indicator",50,2);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

write the code when the post_type == product like below:

```
 if ($post_type === 'product') {

    function your_func(){

    return ;

    }

    add_filter("comment_text","comment_significance_indicator",50,2);

    }
```

Comment: should i cover this code block with another function that is triggered with something, or just put it like this inside functions.php?

Comment: add your function in this condition. make sure you remove post_type condition from your function because the wrapper function already does this.